# Iron PDF Invalid Deployment in test environment

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, ironpdf

We upgraded our version of IronPdf from 2021.3.1. to 2022.2.4887 in a .net core 3.1 web api and all is well in our local environments and on our deployed dev environment. But, when we deployed to our test environment we are now getting errors when attempting to create a pdf from html. I enabled IronPdf logging and get an error saying Invalid Deployment ...\runtimes\win-x64\native\IronInterop.dll

Does anyone have an idea as to what this may be? I have attempted completely clearing out the deployment location of the api and doing a fresh publish and I found one article saying that I should set a custom TempFolderPath, but neither of those made any difference in the error. I don't completely understand this error as the same dll is being used in both our local and dev environments, so I wouldn't think that the dll is corrupted in some way.

Comment: I've got a question in to them, but Stack Overflow gives me access to many more users of the product as well as a potential for a quicker answer. Also if I don't get an answer from stack overflow and I find an answer elsewhere, I can post it here for the next person with this same issue (possibly myself) in a couple years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with IronPDF I did finally get a solution to this issue. The problem was that my test server didn't have the latest C++ redistributables, which evidently weren't required for the version I was using previously. There is now an article in their documentation that includes information on installing the redistributables from Microsoft as well as other troubleshooting steps for this issue: https://ironpdf.com/troubleshooting/failed-to-deploy-nuget-package/